# Accessing YYSTYPE after yypush_parse() finished

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

I was hoping that Bison will keep the last value generated by the last action executed, but that's not the case.  I have no idea where it comes up with what it stores in `YYSTYPE`, but in my case it ends up being `49`, which doesn't correspond to anything in my code... (it's not an ASCII code of the last character, nor the number of characters read so far, nor the number of final state, nor the number of the final rule (although it's close, there are 48 rules in total)).  It may be the value of the one-before-last token... that's something I'm trying to verify right now.

Anyways, how do I access the value produced by the action of `%start` rule after the parser finished?

---

It seems that the value stored in `YYSTYPE` is the one-before-last token processed...

Comment: Do you mean `yylval`? `YYSTYPE` is a typename, not a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bison: where is the last $$ value stored in pure-push parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254587/bison-where-is-the-last-value-stored-in-pure-push-parser)

Comment: @rici yes, however you choose to call it.

Comment: @rici oh well... ok, I'll add more arguments... Wouldn't it be also possible to modify location info to not pass extra arguments?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. In theory, you could use the existing arguments but there is no formal support for that.

Comment: @rici I saw a way one could override the define for `YYLTYPE` to add more fields, but, on a second thought, I can live with an extra argument too.